# Issue with editing ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have developed a boxplot using the following sample code:

```
a<- ggplot(na.omit(df1), aes(x=C, y=E, fill=as.factor(complete), color=as.factor(complete))) + 
         geom_boxplot()

a + ggtitle("Sample Text") +  
    ylab("E") + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name = "Response", labels = c("No", "Yes")) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust=0.5)) + 
    geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge()) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = rep(NA, 2))
```

This results in a sample graph that displays datapoints exactly as I want but results in the legend getting distorted. Is there a way to alter the code to have the legend title as "Response" with "Yes" and 'No" as the legend items?

[image]

Comment: Check your `scale_fill_...` layers: you have two which may be conflicting. If you make your question reproducible by including the data this could be tested. Use `dput(df1)` to add your data to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps you have to add `scale_color_discrete(name = " Response", labels = c("No", "Yes"))`.

Comment: Yes you have both the "color" and "fill" aesthetic defined. If you what both legends to match then you will need to add `scale_color_discrete(name = "Response", labels = c("No", "Yes"))` to the plot definition.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent This definitely helped, thanks!